# Updater & software & updates not updating anything

Tags: package-management, upgrade, update-manager

So first I know absolutely nothing about Xubuntu or Linux whatsoever. I'm basically a laymen when it comes to computers period. Anyway, I'm running Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS thanks to my dad. My software updater keeps notifying me that basically everything needs to be updated at this point but when i click install it gives me an error message saying nothing updated or installed. So I thought I'd be cool and do a lil research and see what i can do. Here's what I came up with:
I used `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` in the command line and this is what it said :

```
jayden@Jay:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
[sudo] password for jayden: 
Ign:1 cdrom://Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731) focal InRelease
Err:2 cdrom://Xubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731) focal Release
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs etc. (too much to copy and paste see attached image)[enter image description here][1]
```

So wtf do I do? please keep in mind I'm clueless. Can i just wipe  the whole computer and download new software starting fresh? If so, how?

Comment: The CDROM reference in your messages refers to the installation media used; when it's a new install it can be useful (*esp. if you have no internet and thus want only to install additional packages on the installation media*), but after then it's mostly just annoying, as we generally don't have that media handy, and it's outdated now anyway.  I'd suggest removing or disabling it (a "#" at the start of the line will disable it by turning the line into a comment).  You can do this via GUI or text editor tool.  Please try looking at *duplicate* for clues.